# How Javascript compare key of Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I am using Javascript ES6 features in a node.js application:

```
class pairKey {
constructor(x_pos, y_pos) {
    this._X = x_pos;
    this._Y = y_pos;
}

get x() {
    return this._X;
}
set x(x_pos) {
    this._X = x_pos;
}

get y() {
    return this._Y;
}
set y(y_pos) {
    this._Y = y_pos;
}


var allElem = new Map();
allElem.set(new pairKey(1,2), 'a');
allElem.set(new pairKey(2,3), 'b');

console.log(allElem.has(new pairKey(1,2))); //Should return true instead return false
```

In this code I want to use a pair of `Int` as key of my map (`allElem`).
The problem is that I don't know how `Map` compare objects in javascript.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your code fails is that Map uses same-value algorithm to match keys. An object instance is not the same value as another object instance, even if both share the same intrinsic value (for examle, try `({a:1} === {a:1})` -> it's false). One way you could make that work for you is to add a key property to your object such that the same intrinsic values generate the exact same key (1 to 1). Then use that key when setting Map entries. See example (Utilizes `Symbol.for` to generate a reproducable key):

```js
'use strict'
class pairKey {
  constructor(x_pos, y_pos) {
    this._X = x_pos;
    this._Y = y_pos;
  }

  get x() {
    return this._X;
  }
  set x(x_pos) {
    this._X = x_pos;
  }

  get y() {
    return this._Y;
  }
  set y(y_pos) {
    this._Y = y_pos;
  }

  get key() {
    return Symbol.for(`pairKey[${this.x}:${this.y}]`);
  }
}
var allElem = new Map();
allElem.set(new pairKey(1, 2).key, 'a');
allElem.set(new pairKey(2, 3).key, 'b');

console.log(allElem.has(new pairKey(1, 2).key));
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `Symbol.for` here, as opposed to using a string?

Comment: @StefanMonov 5+ years ago it seemed to make sense :-D

Answer (score 14):

`Map` does use the [*SameValueZero* algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero) for comparing the keys. This means that reference equality is used for objects, so if you have `a = new PairKey(1, 2)` and `b = new PairKey(1, 2)` they are not the same object - `a !== b`.

So what can you do to solve this? There are basically two ways to solve this:

- use not the object itself as a key, but rather a primitive (e.g. string) representation of it, which can be created from distinct instances with the same value
- use [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) for your key objects, so that `new PairKey` always returns the same object if called with the same arguments

Also you might be able to subclass `Map` where all methods are overwritten so that they handle `PairKey`s specially, relying on one of the above techniques.

Unfortunately, hash consing is impossible to implement without weak references and without leaking memory, so we'll have to resort to the first technique:

```
class Pair {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    toKey() {
        return `Pair(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
    }
    static key(x, y) {
        return new Pair(x, y).toKey();
    }
}

var allElem = new Map(); // string -> string
allElem.set(Pair.key(1, 2), 'a');
allElem.set(Pair.key(2, 3), 'b');

console.log(allElem.has(Pair.key(1, 2))); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

Your map key is an object.  `console.log` returns `false` because you're creating a **new object** to retrieve they key.  It doesn't matter that it has the same pair.  What matters is that it is a **different** new object.

If you want to retrieve the value corresponding to `new pairKey(1,2)` you have to do the following:

```
let key = new pairKey(1,2);
allElem.set(key, 'a');

console.log(allElem.has(key));
```

In other words if you use object as a key, make sure to use the same object to retrieve the value.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize for bringing up the old question, but I found a very interesting solution, inspired by the [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31953390/3339955) and the **hash consing** mentioned as impossible.

```
class PairKey {
  private static cache: Record<string, PairKey> = {};

  constructor(
    private _x: number, private _y: number,
    action: 'create' | 'read' | 'delete' = 'read'
  ) {
      const key = PairKey.key(_x, _y);

      if (action === 'create' || action === 'read') {
        if (PairKey.cache[key]) {
            return PairKey.cache[key];
        }
        if (action === 'create') {
          PairKey.cache[key] = this;
        }
      }
      else if (action === 'delete') {
        delete PairKey.cache[key];
      }
  }

  private static key(x: number, y: number) {
      return `${x}_${y}`;
  }

  get x() {
      return this._x;
  }

  set x(x_pos: number) {
      this._x = x_pos;
  }

  get y() {
      return this._y;
  }

  set y(y_pos: number) {
      this._y = y_pos;
  }
}

const allElem = new Map<PairKey, string>();

allElem.set(new PairKey(1, 2, 'create'), 'a');  // the action flag to prevent a memory leak

allElem.set(new PairKey(2, 3, 'create'), 'b');  // the action flag to prevent a memory leak

console.log(allElem.has(new PairKey(1, 2))); // Returns true

allElem.delete(new PairKey(1, 2, 'delete'));  // the action flag to prevent a memory leak

console.log(allElem.has(new PairKey(1, 2))); // Returns false
```

A similar solution with more static stuff:

```
class PairKey {
  private static cache: Record<string, PairKey> = {};
  private static readonly symbol = Symbol();

  private constructor(private _x: number, private _y: number, symbol: symbol) {
    if (symbol !== PairKey.symbol) {
      throw new Error("Use 'PairKey.create()' instead of constructor");
    }
  }

  static create(x: number, y: number) {
    const key = PairKey.key(x, y);

    if (PairKey.cache[key]) {
      return PairKey.cache[key];
    }

    const pairKey = new PairKey(x, y, PairKey.symbol);
    PairKey.cache[key] = pairKey;
    return pairKey;
  }

  static read(x: number, y: number) {
    const key = PairKey.key(x, y);
    return PairKey.cache[key];
  }

  static delete(x: number, y: number) {
    const key = PairKey.key(x, y);
    const pairKey = PairKey.cache[key];
    delete PairKey.cache[key];
    return pairKey;
  }

  private static key(x: number, y: number) {
    return `${x}_${y}`;
  }

  get x() {
    return this._x;
  }

  set x(x_pos: number) {
    this._x = x_pos;
  }

  get y() {
    return this._y;
  }

  set y(y_pos: number) {
    this._y = y_pos;
  }
}

const allElem = new Map<PairKey, string>();

allElem.set(PairKey.create(1, 2), 'a');
allElem.set(PairKey.create(2, 3), 'b');

console.log(allElem.has(PairKey.read(1, 2))); // Returns true

allElem.delete(PairKey.delete(1, 2));

console.log(allElem.has(PairKey.read(1, 2))); // Returns false
```